# getComputedStyle or currentStyle for border-left-width

Tags: javascript, css

My HTML : `<div id="bar" ></div>`

My CSS :

```
#bar
{
    border-left-width:150px;
}
```

My JS :

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    if(el.currentStyle)var y=el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if(window.getComputedStyle)var y=document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}

alert(getStyle(document.getElementById("bar"),"border-left-width"));//Outputs 0px
```

The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4ABhZ/1

How can I get the `border-left-width` property? (with my exemple it's not working (on firefox))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L2ZwD/ ....................

Comment: your jsfiddle says "0px"

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Give the div some dimensions and color and you'll see why: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Xkxgk/

Comment: The JavaScript is correct. The CSS isn't doing what you think it's doing. You need to provide a `border-left-style` as well. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Xkxgk/

Comment: this works: http://jsfiddle.net/L2ZwD/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Xkxgk/ isnt working for me here on opera and also not in chrome (says 0px again)  you should define the border before or something  see my jsfiddle

Comment: I know, because in the fiddle he wrote, he didn't write a `border-left-style` like he said, but the solution is to set a `border-left-style`

Comment: then your code doesnt work in opera =)

Comment: @DanielRuf Does this work in Opera? http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/4ABhZ/4/

Comment: now it works =) (but my answer was also correct as this is often simpler using jquery for cross browser compatibility and so on)  this is just one reason why there is jquery - write once using 1 markup and it works in all browser ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `border-left-style` property. It's set to `none` (the default). Set it to something like `solid` and you're good to go: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/4ABhZ/4/

Comment: says "undefined" here - opera  so not crossbrowser  better you use jquery (crossbrowser)

Answer (score 1):

To support older browserss you'll need to change the hyphenated-css  to camelCase.

You can use camelCase in the other browsers as well, and
read the properties  of the getComputedStyle object directly.

```
function getStyle(el, css){
    if(window.getComputedStyle) return getComputedStyle(el, '')[css];
    if(el.currentStyle) return el.currentStyle[css];    
}
```

**alert(getStyle(document.getElementById('bar'),'borderTopWidth'));**

Note- the css definition needs a **style** as well as a width for a border to have a computed width (and it can't be set to display:none when you compute its dimensions...)